# Manage permanent URLs with specific HTTP status codes

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps, http, url

I need a web-app for creating permanent URLs that send a given HTTP status code. In case the status code is [3xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection), I want to enter a URI as redirection target.

Ideally it would allow to set specific **phrases** (e.g., "Gone forever" instead of "Gone" for 410) per URL (not globally). And it would be great if I can provide simple text/HTML as **content** per URL.

I’ll be the only one who should be able to create/edit URLs, so I need some kind of **login** (others should not be able to try to register an account).
It should offer some kind of **overview interface** (only accessible after login), where I can check which URLs are created, which status codes are used, etc. (ideally with filter/sort/search).

Workflow:

1. Enter a unique string.
2. Select a HTTP status code.
3. (maybe edit phrase)
4. (maybe add content)
5. If 3xx, enter redirection target URI.

The string entered in step 1 is used for the URL path. For example, when the script is installed at `http://example.com/` and the string is "foo", then the URL `http://example.com/foo` is created.

The solution

- must be **FLOSS**
- must run natively on a **GNU/Linux** server (**self-hosting**)
- must not require Java
- should be in Perl, PHP or Python

---

I assume a [PURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_uniform_resource_locator) server or maybe even an advanced [URL shortener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) could be a solution.

[purlz.org](http://purlz.org/) seems to offer a PURL server, however, it requires Java (if I understand the [readme](http://code.google.com/p/persistenturls/wiki/CurrentREADME) correctly).